# AS3 - Getting the value of a property within another property via square bracket notation

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, reference

I have a class `Inhabitant` with a property `skin` which is of type `DisplayObject`.

Within `Inhabitant` I need to access the `x` and `y` properties of skin using this method:

```
this["someProperty"];
```

Rather than:

```
this.someProperty;
```

This is fine with properties defined within `Inhabitant` but I'm not sure how I could do this for a property of `skin`. This obviously doesn't work but it might give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
this["skin.x"];
```

The reason behind requiring this notation is that I have a function which I can parse a String though that will represent a property:

```
public function addTokenable(property:String):void
{
    if(!isTokenable(property))
        _tokenables[property] = true;
}
```

And then a related getter that will return a representation of this instance of `Inhabitant` as a String:

```
public function get token():String
{
    _token = "class:" + getQualifiedClassName(this).split("::").join(".");

    for(var i:String in _tokenables)
        _token += "#" + i + ":" + this[i];

    return _token;
}
```

This would result in something like:

```
class:terra.environment.Inhabitant#someProperty:someValue#etc:etc
```

The goal is to be able to reference properties of skin within the `addTokenable()` method, so that I can have something along the lines of:

```
var person:Inhabitant = new Inhabitant();

person.skin = new PersonSkin();
person.skin.x = 100;
person.skin.y = 150;

person.addTokenable("skin.x");
person.addTokenable("skin.y");

trace(person.token); // class:terra.environment.Inhabitant#skin.x:100#skin.y:150
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing something like this:

```
for (var i:String in _tokenables) {
    var target:* = this;
    var propList:Array = i.split(".");
    for (var j:Number = 0; j < propList.length; j++) {
        try {
            target = target[propList[j]];
        } catch (e:Error) {
            trace(e.getStackTrace());
            // or whatever other stuff you want to do
        }
    }
    _token += '#' + i + ":" + target;
}
```

For example. "skin.x" will create a propList of ['skin', 'x']
The first iteration through the for loop will set

```
target = this['skin'];
```

And the second will set

```
target = this['skin']['x'];
```

which is the correct bracket notation for accessing the skin property x.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give something like this a go and see how I fare.